# Debugging World Cup Simulator C++

Tags: c++, class, structure, simulator

Here it is my code.  Mostly using structures and classes, some pointers.  But it's not 100% working.  Please welp!

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct team
{
    string name;
    int attack;
    int defence;
    int points;
} team;

typedef struct group
{
    string teamOne;
    string teamTwo;
} group;

void teaminput(team *A);
void Fixture(team& teamA, team& teamB);

int main()
{
    int NumberOfTeams;

    cout << "Welcome to the World Cup Simulator" << endl;
    cout << "\nPlease select the number of teams participating";
    cout << "\n(please note, the required number of teams per group is 4; with";
    cout << "\n the number of groups corresponding to each selection shown below)." << endl;
    cout << "\n 8 (2 groups)";
    cin >> NumberOfTeams;


    if (NumberOfTeams == 8)
    {

        team A;
        teaminput(&A);
        team B;
        teaminput(&B);
        team C;
        teaminput(&C);
        team D;
        teaminput(&D);

        vector<team> groupOne;
        groupOne.push_back(A);
        groupOne.push_back(B);
        groupOne.push_back(C);
        groupOne.push_back(D);

        team E;
        teaminput(&E);
        team F;
        teaminput(&F);
        team G;
        teaminput(&G);
        team H;
        teaminput(&H);

        vector<team> groupTwo;
        groupTwo.push_back(E);
        groupTwo.push_back(F);
        groupTwo.push_back(G);
        groupTwo.push_back(H);

        for (auto teamA = groupOne.begin(); teamA != groupOne.end(); teamA++)
        {
            for (auto teamB = groupTwo.begin(); teamB != groupTwo.end(); teamB++)
            {
                Fixture(*teamA, *teamB);
            }
        }


        cout << "\n" << A.name << "\n" << A.attack << "\n" << A.defence;
    }
    return 0;
}

void teaminput(team *A)
{
    team A;
    string x;
    int y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nPlease enter team " << i + 1 << " data." << endl;

        cout << "\nTeam Name\t\t\t: \t";
        cin >> x;
        A->name = x;//TeamName

        cout << "Attack Level\t\t: \t";
        cin >> y;
        A->attack = y; //AttackLevel

        cout << "Defence Level\t\t: \t";
        cin >> y;
        A->defence = y;//DefenceLevel
    }
}

void Fixture(team& teamA, team& teamB)
{
    //string teamA, teamB;
    int teamAattack, teamBattack = 0;
    int teamAdefence, teamBdefence = 0;
    int teamAgoals = 0, teamBgoals = 0; // previously you were only initializing teamB' variables
    int teamApoints = 0, teamBpoints = 0;

    if (teamA.attack - teamB.defence > 0)
        teamAgoals = teamA.attack - teamB.defence;
    if (teamB.attack - teamA.defence > 0)
        teamBgoals = teamB.attack - teamA.defence;

    if (teamAgoals > teamBgoals)
    {
        teamA.points = teamA.points + 3;
    }
    else if (teamBgoals > teamAgoals)
    {
        teamB.points = teamB.points + 3;
    }
    else if (teamAgoals == teamBgoals)
    {
        teamA.points = teamA.points + 1;
        teamB.points = teamB.points + 1;
    }
}
```

When I run it, it asks for number of teams (which in this case only 8 is a valid input for now).  Then, it asks for team name.  After an input, the program crashes.

What am I missing??

Comment: You really should try to reduce this to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and not just for our sakes-- it can make the bug clear to you.

Comment: You have ``team A``  as a local variable in the input functions and a ``team A*`` as input parameter of the input function. Which one does the function use? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you re-declaring `team A` in `teaminput()`. It looks like you are trying to dereference the local variable instead of the passed in parameter?

Also, why did you code the whole program and only run it now? That's just asking for pain. The lesson here is to test each function as you write it, so that you don't end up with 300 lines of debugging hell.

Finally, a nitpick, a normal coding convention is that `struct`s and `class`es have Capital Names, and functions/primitives should be camelCase (or lowercase_with_underscore if you have something against camels). It makes the code much easier to read.

Comment: Also, when programming it is good practice to debug through new code and focus on data and state as well as control flow. Using debugger is a standard step while programming, not something to use only when problems arise. If the environment is bad for debugging, change it for the better.